# Redirect site.example/guide/* to newsite.example/guide/* with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a WordPress installed in a folder, not the root domain. I have my `.htaccess` file all set up in the root folder, but not for the WordPress folder.

I want to know how to redirect:

- www to non-www
- `site.example/guide/` to `newsite.example/guide/`
- and `site.example/guide/some-article/` to `newsite.example/guide/some-article/`

I was playing around with things, but `site.example/guide/some-article/` was redirecting me to `newsite.example/some-article/`, not `newsite.example/guide/some-article/`. I would post the code here, but I got rid of it and saved the changes.

The www to non-www seems to be working with this snippet:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Couldn't you just sym-link the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add below rules with your short domain redirection rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://site.example%1 [R=301,L]
```